# Netflix's DGS graphql client for upload example

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-dgs, graphqlclient

I am new to graphql and I am trying to use graphql client library from [Netflix dgs framework](https://netflix.github.io/dgs/advanced/java-client/) to call graphql api from Spring framework based Java client. Most of things are working, but struggling to get Upload mutation work. Any one has any examples?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: are you using the gql server in single more or federated mode?